# How can I export saved searches from NetSuite to Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: api, export, data, cloud, issue

I want to export saved searches from NetSuite to Azure Blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

To export saved searches from NetSuite to Azure Blob storage, you can follow these general steps:

1. Create an Azure Blob storage account: You will need to create an Azure Blob storage account if you don't already have one. You can create one using the Azure Portal or Azure CLI.
2. Set up NetSuite integration with Azure Blob storage: To set up integration between NetSuite and Azure Blob storage, you can use the NetSuite SuiteTalk web services API and the Azure Blob storage REST API. You can use an integration platform like Dell Boomi, Mulesoft, or Azure Logic Apps to automate this process.
3. Write a script to extract data from NetSuite: You can use the NetSuite SuiteTalk web services API to extract data from saved searches in NetSuite. You can write a script in any programming language that supports web services, such as Java, Python, or C#.
4. Convert data to CSV format: Once you have extracted data from NetSuite, you will need to convert it to CSV format. You can use a CSV library in your programming language of choice to do this.
5. Upload CSV files to Azure Blob storage: Once the CSV files are created, you can use the Azure Blob storage REST API to upload them to Azure Blob storage.
6. Set up a schedule to automate the export process: You can use an integration platform like Dell Boomi, Mulesoft, or Azure Logic Apps to schedule the export process at regular intervals.

Alternatively, you can use a third-party tool like Skyvia or Celigo to export saved searches from NetSuite to Azure Blob storage without having to write any code. These tools provide a drag-and-drop interface that makes it easy to set up the integration and automate the export process.